# Use celery to receive redis pubsub messages

Tags: python, redis, celery, publish-subscribe

I'd like to send redis subpub (or sqs) messages to a flask app and have the app act upon receiving message. I'm thinking to use celery, but I can't figure out how to have celery run in the background and act when a message is received. Any thoughts?

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: i ended up using a combo of redis, sqs, and a lambda to accomplish what was needed.